# How to convert list[x] value into string

Tags: python

```
obj.li_table[machine_IP] value contains \\\\10.10.10.10

system = str(obj.li_table[machine_IP])

print (system)
```

the output is displayed as shown below

```
['\\\\10.10.10.10']
```

But what should be done to display the above value as

```
\\\\10.10.10.10
```

Comment: `system = str(obj.li_table[0])` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this works in Python3:

```
class object_class:
    def __init__(self):
        self.li_table = ['\\\\10.10.10.10']

obj = object_class()
system = str(obj.li_table[0])
print(system)
```

output:

```
\\10.10.10.10
```

or, if you really want the 4x `\` in the output, you can use a raw `r` string in the `obj.li_table[r'\\\\10.10.10.10]`:

```
class object_class:
    def __init__(self):
        self.li_table = [r'\\\\10.10.10.10']

obj = object_class()
system = str(obj.li_table[0])
print(system)
```

output:

```
\\\\10.10.10.10
```